# Unable to open Encryption Box in a Buffalo MiniStation HD-PCU2

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, disk-encryption

When I try to open one of the "Encryption Box" (Software: SecureLockMobile v1.7) on my BUFFALO MiniStation HD-PCU2  I get the message: "Unable to open file".

It does not happen with the others "Encryption Box".

Can someone help me?

Advance grateful.

Jorge

Comment: What's an Encryption Box?

Comment: The software included in the BUFFALO MiniStation HD-PCU2 creates partitions(?)  to encrypt the files, which it calls: "Encryption Box".

Comment: Hmm... it must use some optional software for that, otherwise it appears to be a regular external hard drive... do you know what the encryption software is?  Maybe it's help is better. Searching I only found your post on buffalotech's forums...

Comment: Software: SecureLockMobile v1.7 
 
Thanks for the clue.